# How can I read and write data from a specific port to the console?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-node

I'm writing a listener service. Data is streaming to me from a specific port. But I cannot read the incoming data and write to consola.

I have a listener service written in GoLang. I tried to extract the listener logic from these codes and adapt it for node.js. But I couldn't.

My service can listen to the port, there is no problem in this regard. Because the place where I get the data produces output because your service is running on its side.

[Message returning to me from the place that sent data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntVbg.png)

These are my proto codes:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "rpc_base_msg.proto";

//----------Remote Process Control Models BEGIN----------//
message RPCKeyboardActivityRequest {
  RequestModel request_model = 1;
}
message RPCKeyboardActivityResponse {
  ResponseModel response_model =1;
}
//----------Remote Process Control Models END-----------//


//---------------Data Tranfer Models BEGIN-------------//
message DTKeyboardActivityModel {
  uint64 dt     = 1;   // Date-Time Stamp
  enum Activity {
    APPLICATION = 0;
    WEB_BROWSER = 1;
  }
  Activity  activity         = 2;   // Activity: Can be application or a web browser.
  string     activity_name   = 3;   //Activity is the name of the application or web page name
  string     key             = 4;   // This is the user's keystroke sequence. Changes for every different application or same application in every 60 seconds!!!
  bool islive_data=5;
  uint64 delete_id=6;
}
message DTKeyboardActivityRequest {
  DTKeyboardActivityModel dt_keyboard_activity_model = 1;
}
message DTKeyboardActivityResponse {
  bool ret_complete = 1;    // Return True/False
}
//---------------Data Tranfer Models END-------------//


//----------------Service BEGIN------------------//
service ActivityService {
  rpc SSPCKeyboardActivity (RPCKeyboardActivityRequest) returns (stream RPCKeyboardActivityResponse);
  rpc UDTKeyboardActivity (DTKeyboardActivityRequest) returns (DTKeyboardActivityResponse);
  rpc BDSDTKeyboardActivity (stream DTKeyboardActivityRequest) returns (stream DTKeyboardActivityResponse);
}
//----------------Service END------------------//
```

These are the proto import codes:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message RequestModel {
    bool is_process_completed = 1;
}

message ResponseModel {
    bool is_monitoring = 1;
}
```

These are my listen service codes:

```
const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const path = "./protos/test.proto";
const path2= "./protos/activity.proto";

const packageDefination = protoLoader.loadSync(path,{
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
});

const packageDef = protoLoader.loadSync(path2,{
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
});

const test_proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefination);
const activity_proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDef);


function sayHello(call,callback) {
    callback(null,{message:'Hello '+ call.request.name});
}

function sayHelloAgain(call,callback) {
    callback(null,{message:'Hello Again ' + call.request.name});
}

function SSPCKeyboardActivity(call){
    let rpcKeyboardActivityRequest = call.request.RPCKeyboardActivityRequest;
    console.log("rpcKeyboardActivityRequest:" + rpcKeyboardActivityRequest);

    let monitorStatusChange = true;
    let whileControl = true;

    console.log("SSPCKeyboardActivity client recv :" + GetRequestModel());

    while (whileControl === true){

        call.write({IsMonitoring: monitorStatusChange})
        monitorStatusChange = !monitorStatusChange;
        if (!monitorStatusChange){
            setTimeout(function () {},30000)
        }else {
            setTimeout(function () {},10000)
        }
    }
}

function UDTKeyboardActivity(call,callback) {

    let context = call.metadata.get('context.Context');
    console.log("Context" + context);

    if (context){

        let udtKeyboardActivity = call.request.DTKeyboardActivityRequest;
        console.log("udtKeyboardActivity" + udtKeyboardActivity);

        let dtKeyboardActivityResponse = call.request.DTKeyboardActivityResponse;
        console.log("dtKeyboardActivityResponse" + dtKeyboardActivityResponse);

        callback(null , dtKeyboardActivityResponse);
        console.log("CallBack" + callback);

    }else {

        console.log("Contex Error");

    }
}


function BDSDTKeyboardActivity(call) {
    call.on('data', function () {
        let dtKeyboardActivityRequest = call.request.DTKeyboardActivityRequest;
        console.log("dtKeyboardActivityRequest" + dtKeyboardActivityRequest);

    })
    call.on('end',function () {
        call.write(DTKeyboardActivityResponse);
        console.log("Write DTKeyboardActivityResponse"+DTKeyboardActivityResponse);
    })
}

function main(){
    const server = new grpc.Server();
    server.bindAsync('0.0.0.0:5801',grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),()=>{
        server.start();
        console.log("Server listening at :5801");
    });

    server.addService(test_proto.Greeter.service,{
        sayHello: sayHello,
        sayAgainHello: sayHelloAgain
    });

    server.addService(activity_proto.ActivityService.service, {
        SSPCKeyboardActivity : SSPCKeyboardActivity,
        UDTKeyboardActivity: UDTKeyboardActivity,
        BDSDTKeyboardActivity: BDSDTKeyboardActivity,
    })

}

main();
```

"path" and testproto are not a problem for me. I ran it. I am having a problem with activity_proto.

I came across after the service was running:

```
➜  service node server/server.js
Server listening at :5801
```

As an example, I also share the functions in the service code block written in go.

```
package service

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/******/pb"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type ActivityServer struct {
}

type ActivityRpcUpdateModel struct {
    IsMonitor bool
}

func NewActivityServer() *ActivityServer {
    return &ActivityServer{}
}

func (a *ActivityServer) SSPCKeyboardActivity(request *pb.RPCKeyboardActivityRequest, server pb.ActivityService_SSPCKeyboardActivityServer)
error {

    monitorStatusChange := true
    log.Printf("SSPCKeyboardActivity client recv : %v", request.GetRequestModel())
    for {
        err := server.Send(&pb.RPCKeyboardActivityResponse{ResponseModel: &pb.ResponseModel{IsMonitoring: monitorStatusChange}})
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("SSPCForegroundApp err : %v", err)
        }
        monitorStatusChange = !monitorStatusChange
        if !monitorStatusChange {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 30)
        } else {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
        }
    }
}

func (a *ActivityServer) UDTKeyboardActivity(
    ctx context.Context,
    request *pb.DTKeyboardActivityRequest,
) (*pb.DTKeyboardActivityResponse, error) {
    log.Println(request.GetDtKeyboardActivityModel())

    return &pb.DTKeyboardActivityResponse{
        RetComplete: true,
    }, nil
}

func (a *ActivityServer) BDSDTKeyboardActivity(
    server pb.ActivityService_BDSDTKeyboardActivityServer,
) error {
    panic("implement me")
}
```

I cannot catch the incoming data. And I can't see in the consol. What kind of changes should I make to my functions on the node.js side of me?